# UTF8 encoding with czech characters

Tags: r

I created R project, but I struggle with some czech characters. For example

```
print("Příliš žluťoučký kůň ů úpěl ďábelské ódy")
```

returns

> [1] "Príliš žlutoucký kun u úpel dábelské ódy"

Although some characters were properly printed, most of them not. Also when I create dataframe with this string, same characters are messed up.

```
View(data.frame("Příliš žluťoučký kůň ů úpěl ďábelské ódy"))
```

Comment: I assume you are running R under Windows? Does setting Czech locale help? `Sys.setlocale(locale='Czech')`

Comment: @RobertHacken Windows is natively Unicode and this page proves it - SO is an ASP.NET site running on Windows. *R* and *R-Studio* on the other hand, aren't compiled as Unicode applications(except on Windows), creating quite a few problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Windows’ native UTF-8 support is still experimental, and this page proves nothing. Either way, *R* under Windows, until recently, wasn’t natively UTF-8. So it also depends on the version OP is using.

Comment: @KonradRudolph no. R is compiled for Unicode on Windows. Any bugs remain when displaying text with the wrong font, or using plugins compiled for ASCII. The OP's text is most definitely *not* Unicode. If it was, every non-US-ASCII character would appear as two characters. The fact it doesn't means it's a different single-byte codepage

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You seem to conflating Unicode and UTF-8. The two are very crucially not the same, and until the current release R on Windows did *not* use UTF-8 by default internally. And your other assertion makes no sense: “every non-US-ASCII character would appear as two characters” — uuh, no?! If RStudio saves OP’s file as (e.g.) UTF-8, it wouldn’t appear as two characters; neither here nor (necessarily) in R without UTF-8 codepage. What makes you say so?

Comment: @prdel99 how is this script saved? What OS are you using? In UTF8 non-US-ASCII characters use *two* bytes. The fact your string is still legible means it's an *ASCII* string displayed using the wrong codepage. I suspect the script file was saved using Windows-1250/ISO-8859-2 and displayed on an a machine whose codepage is Latin1/ISO-8859-1

Comment: @KonradRudolph UTF8 is a Unicode encoding. It's not just that Greek requires Unicode, so I've been using it for 30 years. I've seen such problems with R for the last 10 years, checked the actual C++ code (which is why I know it uses wchar on Windows, char elsewhere). Problems that don't exist in programming languages like Java, Javascript, C#. At first, R and RStudio made a huge mess. Then RStudio started using saving files as UTF8, but still had problems with the console and watch windows. Then R methods started accepting an encoding parameter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You don't have to save anything, just copy the `print("Příliš žluťoučký")` command, paste it in the RStudio console and if you are under Windows and don't have the right locale set, diacritics will be stripped from some characters in the output.

Comment: @RobertHacken not in the latest R version. It's an R bug after all - if you execute the command in the terminal with older versions you get some mangled characters. After updating to 4.2.1, the characters aren't mangled any more, no matter the settings.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, that's definitely good news!

Comment: @RobertHacken I have mixed feelings about this. I thought I had last seen these gremlins 10 years ago. Even stranger, running 4.1.3 from the terminal affects even *pasting* the text. In the same terminal, 4.2.1 works fine. Which means 4.1.3 was trying to "fix" codepages, thus breaking them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an R bug that's fixed in the latest version, 4.2.1. I was able to reproduce the problem on Windows in the *RStudio terminal* with 4.1.3.

Upgrading to 4.2.1 fixed the problem :

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
...
> print("Příliš žluťoučký kůň ů úpěl ďábelské ódy")
[1] "Příliš žluťoučký kůň ů úpěl ďábelské ódy"
```

There was no need to change any locale or codepage settings.

It seems that 4.1.3 tries to change terminal settings to "fix" codepage issues. In the same terminal window, running R 4.1.3 causes *pasting* to cut diacritics. I can't even paste the original text.

In the same terminal, running R 4.2.1 after 4.1.3 works just fine. At the very least this means that 4.1.3 was modifying console settings.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your *locale* is not set to UTF8. You can change this with `Sys.setlocale`.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")
print("Příliš žluťoučký kůň ů úpěl ďábelské ódy")
#[1] "P\305\231\303\255li\305\241 \305\276lu\305\245ou\304\215k\303\275 k\305\257\305\210 \305\257 \303\272p\304\233l \304\217\303\241belsk\303\251 \303\263dy"

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "de_DE.UTF-8")  # Linux, macOS, other Unix-alikes
print("Příliš žluťoučký kůň ů úpěl ďábelské ódy")
#[1] "Příliš žluťoučký kůň ů úpěl ďábelské ódy"

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "de")     # Solaris: details are OS-dependent
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "de_DE")  # Many Unix-alikes
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "de_DE.UTF-8")  # Linux, macOS, other Unix-alikes
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "de_DE.utf8")   # some Linux versions
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "German.UTF-8") # Windows
```

Also there was a BUG FIX on Windows for **R 4.2.1 patched**: *Non-ASCII characters are now properly displayed on Windows in windows created using GraphApp via e.g. winDialogString thanks to a workaround for an at least surprising Windows behavior with UTF-8 as the system encoding ([PR#18382](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18382)).*

Comment: It's almost certain the text *isn't* Unicode to begin with. This page is UTF8. The OP's string is just Latin1. Windows is natively Unicode and StackOverflow itself is an ASP.NET application running on Windows. If there was a Unicode encoding issue, any non-US-ASCII character would appear as 2 characters. Either the OP's machine doesn't have a font that handles Latin1 characters (impossible) or the text is *not* Unicode at all